# javascript/jquery digital clock script in 24 hour format with Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am looking for javascript/jquery digital clock script in 24 hour format with Date. The clock should display images as its numbers and date; also the clock should initialize its time from a hidden field having server time. I am using asp.net.

Comment: Why don't use google ? We are not here to make homework or search for you, we are here to solve together the issues/problems met in programming.

Comment: @Michael - i am not asking u to do my homework, if u dont know the answer then please dont comment.

Answer (score 2):

In all seriousness, how much searching did you do? I simply typed 'jquery digital clock' into google and got loads of results, here's one in particular:

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-cool-jquery-clock-tutorials-analog-digital/#.UCjA_SLYEpo

Comment: Sorry Guys, I did searched in google but didnt get any as per my requirement.

Comment: We may have seemed "harsh" in our comments and answers. But this really isn't the type of question that will get a positive answer. Do some more research and try things out, then if you're stuck, come back with more specific problems/questions.